# Compare inputfield with Array

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode

I am doing an app where user can guess the name in the image and check it, i am able to see put the name of the images in the array and able to see it but i need to compare the input string with the array

I already try use if(inputfield == images[i]){
retun "Correct" else{ false 
the answer give me false when i input Apple

```
let images: [String] =["apple","ball","cat","dog","elephant","frog","house","igloo","jar","kite","leaf","monkey","nose","orange","plane","queen","rope","sun","tub","goat"]
var i : Int = 1
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    guessInput.delegate = self
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: images[0])
}

@IBAction func nextButton(_ sender: UIButton) {// Able to show images
   if(i+1 > images.count){
       i = 0
    }
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: images[i])
    i += 1
    checkLabel.text = ""
    guessInput.text = ""
}
@IBAction func checkButton(_ sender: UIButton) {// Compare input with Array
    let tr = String(guessInput.text!)
    if(images[i] ==  tr){
        checkLabel.text = "Correct"
    }
    else{
        checkLabel.text = "false"
    }
}
```

}

I was expected to be out "Correct" when i input was apple but when i press check button it show  false

Comment: Try to always use === check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `compare` the string `caseInsensitive` and creating a string from a string (`String(guessInput.text!)`) is redundant.

```
@IBAction func checkButton(_ sender: UIButton) {// Compare input with Array
    if images[i].compare(guessInput.text!, options: .caseInsensitive) == .orderedSame {
        checkLabel.text = "Correct"
    } else {
        checkLabel.text = "False"
    }
}
```

By the way the compiler will complain about the missing whitespace in the expression `=["apple"`and don't annotate a type which the compiler can infer.

```
let images = ["apple",...
var i = 0 // array indices start with 0
```

And you can replace

```
if(i+1 > images.count){
   i = 0
}
imageView.image = UIImage(named: images[i])
i += 1
```

with

```
i = (i + 1) % images.count
imageView.image = UIImage(named: images[i])
```

The `%` operator warps the index

---

Finally this is Swift: No parentheses around `if` expressions.

Edit:

To keep the index the same

Comment: Thx , the problem was my i =1 but then i change to 0 is work but when i press next button like u suggested i+1 the image still same (apple)[0]  click next apple[1] but when i input in the field as apple for apple[1] it was wrong but when i input ball is correct any idea how to over come this , i already remove the images[i] from the view did load

Comment: Once again, array indices start with 0, The first element is `images[0]` the second is `images[1]` and so on. My code and my suggenstions do work.

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't  seem to work because when i click next button the apple image comeout when i type apple is false but when i type ball it return true

Comment: I updated the answer. In `nextButton` you have first to increment the index then get the image.

Answer (score 0):

Compare the `lowercased()` version of text, i.e.

```
if(images[i] == tr.lowercased()){
    checkLabel.text = "Correct"
}
else {
    checkLabel.text = "false"
}
```

You can shorten it down to,

```
checkLabel.text = (images[i] == tr.lowercased()) ? "Correct" : "false"
```